# replace digits at the end of a int64 in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

My dataframe column is like this format 201902. 4 digits for year and two digits for month

I would like to compare YearMonth with MinPurchaseYearMonth in which I replace month by 01

This is my code that just compare with MinPurchaseYearMonth

```
tx_merge_mindate.loc[q1['YearMonth']>tx_merge_mindate['MinPurchaseYearMonth'],'UserType'] = 'Existing'
```

I would like to replace MinPurchaseYearMonth last 2 digits by 01

I think I can transfer to string to cut last 2 digits, but how can I add 01 at the end ?

```
tx_merge_mindate.loc[q1['YearMonth']>tx_merge_mindate['MinPurchaseYearMonth'].astype(str).str[:-2],'UserType'] = 'Existing'
```

Comment: `tx_merge_mindate['MinPurchaseYearMonth'] -= tx_merge_mindate['MinPurchaseYearMonth'] % 100 - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it numerically or with `str` slicing. The latter is probably slower but it can be an useful trick sometimes:

```
#setup:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[201902, 201107, 200011]})
#     date
#0  201902
#1  201107
#2  200011
```

1. numerically:

```
df["date"] -= df["date"] % 100 -1
#     date
#0  201901
#1  201101
#2  200001
#dtype: int64
```

2. `str` slicing

```
df["date"] = df["date"].astype(str).str[:-2] + "01"
#     date
#0  201901
#1  201101
#2  200001
#dtype: object
```